# Use m3u8 playlist with BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

Can I play a [m3u8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) file on a BlackBerry?  I have a m3u8 file on my server and would like to stream it to my BlackBerry.

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt seem to be able to.

(Tried this url: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

on my Blackberry 8310 (os 4.5) and also tried on a 8320 simulator. )

The official pdf doesnt mention it either:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18349/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf